# firebase function 'npm install -g firebase-tools error'

Tags: node.js, firebase, nodes, npm-install

'npm install -g firebase-tools' enter commond but show some error
 i am using Node v6.11.2 , npm 3.10.10.

> C:\Users\Tahir Ali Awan>npm install -g firebase-tools
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "firebase-tools"
>   npm ERR! node v6.11.2
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>   npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\TAHIRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10928-4df4b0d9\registry.npmjs.org\firebase-tools-\firebase-tools-3.17.4.tgz
>   npm ERR! Expected: dde15ee12a6fa9930a4142b7dafd12313f6555d8
>   npm ERR! Actual:   f5bab81f9dd43c342c2fda6eedbd23f67c1f82e7
>   npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tools/-/firebase-tools-3.17.4.tgz
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tahir Ali Awan\npm-debug.log

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH9g5.png)

Comment: Looks like something is messing with your internet connection. `npm` verifies the download by checking the hashes. The error message states, that there is a mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this two things:

1. Clear the NPM Cache by running "npm clean cache"
2. Try upgrading your node version to the latest stable one

Comment: thanks @sundar my problem solve but another problem ( npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead)